# How to create table structure (tr elements) dynamically (from JSON) in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, json

How can I fill in the following table html structure with json data in a dynamic way? (with AngularJS).

Here is the basic HTML structure:

```html
<table class="some styling">
                    <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><a title="test" href="#"><span>Just some tests</span></a></td>
    <td><a title="test" href="#"><span>Just some tests</span></a></td>
    <td><a title="test" href="#"><span>Just some tests</span></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><a title="test" href="#"><span>Just some tests</span></a></td>
  <td><a title="test" href="#"><span>Just some tests</span></a></td>
  <td><a title="test" href="#"><span>Just some tests</span></a></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

The difficult part is how to determine the "tr" elements. 
There are always 3 td elements in 1 tr element. Only the amount of TD elements may vary.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which code have you written in angular ? show your json

Comment: Are you looking for `ng-repeat`? It very much depends how your JSON / Array looks like.

Comment: And yes I know I should use "ng-repeat" but I don't know how I can provide dynamic rows

Comment: dynamic rows will be craeated based on json data. you can use ng-repeat  i will post the example for this

Answer (score 1):

```
Html:
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse">
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
         <th>firstname</th>
          <th>lastname</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td>{{user.firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{user.lastname}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Json:

```
$scope.users=[
    {id:1,firstname:"naresh",lastname:"kumar"},
    {id:2,firstname:"suresh",lastname:"kumar"},
    {id:3,firstname:"harish",lastname:"kumar"},
    ]
```

this is the example am posting you can manipulate it. you can a have look here https://plnkr.co/edit/umC2hwECePaAqZ0huYoK?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand your example but in my case it's different. I don't need different values likes id,firstname,lastname. I have to show only the site's name. I thought something like this: 

<tr ng-repeat="item in navigationData">
                                    <td><span>{{navigationData[$index].name}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{navigationData[$index+1].name}}</span></td>
        <td><span>{{navigationData[$index+2].name}}</span></td>
                            </tr>

But it still does not work..

Comment: So I need something like this: (example)
'[SiteA][SiteB][SiteC]
[SiteAA][SiteBB][SiteCC]
[SiteAAA][SiteBBB][SiteCCC]'
...
Always 3 columns but different rows